# SharePoint Wizard fails at step 8 : Failed to install the application content files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

I am getting error

> failed to install the application content files 
>   System.NullReferenceException was thrown.  Additional exception
>   information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

this happens after upgrading the SQL Server from evaluation to enterprise.

Plus the SharePoint Timer Service keeps stopping every time I run the `SP_Config` Wizard.

Please help. I tried the `psconfig`

```
-cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait –force
```

but it didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0):

If this is a farm with more than one SharePoint-server, run the following command on the failing server:

```
Get-SPProduct -local
```

Wait. Wait a little longer, since it takes a while to run. It will reset the patch upgrade cache which sometimes fails. When finished, run the PSConfig.exe script again.

Still in trouble? Open the log-file (stated in the CMD window) and find a more detailed error report.

Comment: Hi Benny, This is only a single server Farm,should I continue with that command.

Comment: @Calvin_Klyn Yes. It does no harm to SharePoint. I just wanted to clarify that you need to run the script on the failing server. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Remove all comment from your web.config files and rerun the configuration wizard again, it should work. I know this because I've also experienced that issue.

ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/support/administration/nullreferenceexception-for-configuration-wizard